# How can I use get values from array of objects from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to learn how to use API's in react. I am making a search input for country names using the Rest countires API. I am getting data from https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all but I do not know how to handle this data as I can not use map on an object.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
 const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
 const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
    setCountries(response.data);
   });
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = event => {
  setSearchName(event.target.value);
   };


   return (
  <div>
    <div>
      find countries <input onChange={handleSearch} />
    </div>
   <div></div>
  </div>
  );
 };

 export default App;
```

Expected to list countries after typing such as : sw = Botswana, Swaziland, Sweden ...

Comment: I just checked the api the data seems to be an array of objects. Is that right?

Comment: looks like you are trying to get the response from: response.data - but the response is not an object with data property - so try remove the .data and use the response only. the response is an array - so you will be able to map over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it seems like, these are requirements of your app -
  1

1. you need to search by country name
2. As you type in, list of countries matching the search should be displayed.

I created this sandbox with the code you provided - https://codesandbox.io/embed/58115762-rest-countries-o638k.

> It shows a pair of country name and its capital as you enter input in the search box.

This is how I changed your code:

1. You need to search countries? - Use `search` API with country name as value of text input - `searchName`

> https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${searchName}

2. To display the output with countries matching your search keyword - `map` over `countries` and get appropriate keys. Pass those keys as props to your newly created `Country` component.

   > Note, I did not need to change how you handled the JSON response. The `searchName` and `countries` are the only two state variables used to render the UI.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to render countries after fetching from ajax request as like :

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

 const App = () => {
 const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
 const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
 axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
  setCountries(response.data);
 });
 }, []);

 const handleSearch = event => {
 setSearchName(event.target.value);
 };


 return (
  <div>
  <div>
   find countries <input onChange={handleSearch} />
  </div>
  <ul>
    {(countries.length<=0)?"":
    countries.map(country=> <li>country.name</li> )
        }
  </ul>
 </div>
);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. 
If you have got questions, dont hesitate to ask :)

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = event => {
    let str = event.target.value;
    let filteredCountries = countries.filter((country) => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase()));
    setCountries(filteredCountries);
    setSearchName(str);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        find countries <input onChange={handleSearch} />
      </div>
      <ul> {(countries.length <= 0) ? "" : countries.map(country => <li>{country.name}</li>) } </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data =[your array];
countryList = data.map(data=>data.name)
console.log(countryList)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.